# Windows unresponsive, CPU utilization uninformative

Tags: windows-7, windows, performance, freeze, cpu-usage

In many situations my Windows 7 box becomes unresponsive, but the Task Manager shows 0 CPU utilization for all processes.

Obviously it is the kernel/Windows itself that is sucking all the cycles and not reporting what activity is sucking cycles. How can I find out where the cycles are going (short of using WinDBG or other kernel debugger)?

Comment: Are you running Task Manager as Administrator (so you can see all  processes)?

Comment: Why are you against using a kernel debugger?

Comment: This could be a sign of failing hardware...

Comment: Yes, I am running task manager as administrator. I am hoping for a simple way to find out why the kernel is hanging. My sense is that using a kernel debugger is way too complicated.

Comment: use xperf to capture the CPU activity: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD